# SQL Server - Multiple SUM CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server, optimization, sum, conditional-statements, case-when

First time posting so forgive me if this has been asked before.
I am not new to writing SQL but I am also no expert.

I need a better way to write this:

```
CASE
WHEN OrderQuantity + Week1Quantity >= CriteriaAmount THEN 1
WHEN OrderQuantity + Week1Quantity + Week2Quantity >= CriteriaAmount THEN 2
WHEN OrderQuantity + Week1Quantity + Week2Quantity + Week3Quantity >= CriteriaAmount THEN 3
WHEN OrderQuantity + Week1Quantity + Week2Quantity + Week3Quantity + Week4Quantity >= CriteriaAmount THEN 4
WHEN OrderQuantity + Week1Quantity + Week2Quantity + Week3Quantity + Week4Quantity + Week5Quantity >= CriteriaAmount THEN 5
WHEN OrderQuantity + Week1Quantity + Week2Quantity + Week3Quantity + Week4Quantity + Week5Quantity + Week6Quantity >= CriteriaAmount THEN 6
WHEN OrderQuantity + Week1Quantity + Week2Quantity + Week3Quantity + Week4Quantity + Week5Quantity + Week6Quantity + Week7Quantity > CriteriaAmount THEN 7
WHEN OrderQuantity + Week1Quantity + Week2Quantity + Week3Quantity + Week4Quantity + Week5Quantity + Week6Quantity + Week7Quantity + Week8Quantity >= CriteriaAmount THEN 8
ELSE 999
END
```

It's purpose is to find the first stage at which the target is hit, using numeric values from each column as a running total.

Table like so:

<kbd>Order Quantity</kbd><kbd>Week 1</kbd><kbd>Week 2</kbd><kbd>Week 3</kbd><kbd>(Suggested Target)</kbd>
<kbd>.........5............</kbd><kbd>.....5......</kbd><kbd>.....5......</kbd><kbd>.....5......</kbd><kbd>............15.............</kbd>
<kbd>........10...........</kbd><kbd>....10.....</kbd><kbd>....10.....</kbd><kbd>....10.....</kbd><kbd>............500...........</kbd>

In the above table row 1 will give an answer of 2 as there are 2 weeks to add to reach the target. 
Row 2 will land on the ELSE statement giving 999 which will later be converted to an error.

I would like a better way to write this as I have 52 more columns to get through you can imagine this is a white-space-hog!

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design of table is very poor. After a few years it will have hundreds of columns. The only way to deal with this, if you cannot change the table design, is to use dynamic sql with exec.

The sane, and maintainable, approach is to change the table design to have one row for each item number, week number and item amount. Then you can use standard TSQL verbs such as sum and group by.

Comment: The table design is limited to 52 columns - number of weeks in year. Say the initial order amount is for 1 mars bar. Basically this is to calculate how many mars bars will fit in a box, the suggested target being the box size. The caveat is that it has to work for different size items, like twixs too. So I have already calculated the combined size of mars bars and twixs for each week, now I need to get as close to that total as possible to not waste any space in the box.

Comment: Even with 'only' 52 repeating columns it will be very challenging to write sql statements against such a table. A sql server table is not Excel. If you can change your table design now or you will have to engage in really extensive workarounds every time you use this table.

Comment: Please can you suggest a table design? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: You probably need 3 tables. Table one is Item number, order quantity. Table two is item number, week number, quantity. Table 3 is item number, suggested target. This is a relational design and then you can do 'standard' sql against these tables.

Comment: A relational design has no repeating columns and every column  in a table is dependent on the primary key and only on the primary key.

Comment: To finish this up, I re-structured my table design as per your comments, thanks.